# How to display a text after user select the variations of product

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When user select the variation of product and then check if price is over 150 then i want to display a message that product is eligible for free shipping. I have created a code but its not working :

```
function echo_variation_price() {
   global $product;
   if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return;
   echo '<div class="var_info"></div>';
   wc_enqueue_js( "
      $(document).on('found_variation', 'form.cart', function( event, variation ) { 
         var var_prod_price = parseFloat(variation.price_html);
         if (var_prod_price > 150);
            $('.var_info').html('Free Shipping Available');
         
      });
   " );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'echo_variation_price' );
```